# OpenVPN create a connection, run a script and shut it down

Tags: linux, openvpn

What would be the best way of going about the following problem?

I have a server that I periodically dump backups to. The only way to connect to this server is via OpenVPN. So far I tested everything manually and it worked fine. Here's what I do:

1. run openvpn --config my-server-connection-details.ovpn
2. in second screen console window I mount NFS share, perform the copy and unmount it
3. I go back to screen console 1 and ctrl+c the connection.

How can I best script it so I can just put it in cron? I'm mostly inquiring about the openvpn part, as the rest seems clear to me and I'm an OpenVPN / VPN newbie. The client is a linux machine.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What distribution of Linux?   This should be trivial on Debian/Ubuntu.

Setup your config in `/etc/openvpn/myvpn.conf`, adjust your `/etc/default/openvpn` file so vpns are not automatically started.

Then your script does something like this.  No need to use screen or anything fancy.

```
#!/bin/sh
/etc/init.d/openvpn start myvpn
mount /nfs
rsync src dst
/etc/init.d/openvpn stop myvpn
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. Simple and easy. Thank you for your advice!